# fetch json decoded array using php foreach loop

Tags: php, json, curl, foreach

i have a json decoded array like $json = json_decode($curl_result);  how to fetch this array using foreach loop and i want to reduce the array looping as much as possible. can you write the correct code that i can access these values.

the array is looking like below

```
  Array
  (
    [SITEResponse] => Array
    (
        [@version] => 1.0
        [SoftwareProducts] => Array
        (
            [@numFound] => 408
            [@numReturned] => 10
            [@start] => 0
            [SoftwareProduct] => Array
            (
              [0] => Array
                  (
                    [Summary] => Array
                    (
                         [$] => summery of software.
                    )
                    [Requirements] => Array
                    (
                    )

                    [ContentIds] => Array
                    (
                    )

                    [CleverBridgeUrl] => Array
                    (
                    )

                    [BuyNowUrl] => Array
                    (
                        [$] => http://www.abc.com
                        [@type] => dl_buy_pub
                    )

                    [BetaRelease] => Array
                    (
                        [$] => false
                    )

                    [LinkURL] => Array
                    (
                    [$] => http://www.abc.com
                    )
                )       
            )
        )
    )
)
```

now i want to get each value of this array but how??? please help
thanks.

Comment: Create a function which gives you the output in a dynamic way. 
For example: foreach ($json as $key => $val) { 
  if (is_array($val)) {
     CALL A FUNCTION THAT SCANS A ARRAY..
}
}
Else you can do it statically by specifying that array name:
$output['SITEResponse'] will be Array
$output['SITEResponse']['version'] will be 1.0
similarly you can do this other values..

Answer (score 1):

```
$version = $json['SITEResponse']['@version'];
$numFound = $json['SITEResponse']['SoftwareProducts']['@numFound'];
...
...

foreach( $json['SITEResponse']['SoftwareProducts']['SoftwareProduct'] as $key=>$product ){
$Summary= $product['Summary']['$'];
$BuyNowUrl = $product['BuyNowUrl']['$'];
...
...
...
}
```